# Delete photos from Google 'your photos'

Tags: google-drive, google-photos

I have shared some pictures 3 years ago through Google. I have deleted all my photos from Google Drive, but whenever I click on 'Your photos' it shows me the photos I have shared through Google Talk. I want to delete those photos.

Answer (score 1):

Because the photos were loaded through Google Talk, you may need to use [Google Album Archive](https://get.google.com/albumarchive/) to delete them.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why it hasn't been deleted was probably because you used Google Talk you should use something like Google Archive.